# ExoPlayer playing currently recording media files

Tags: android, exoplayer

Let me refraise my question, I wrote it in a hurry.

Current situation:
I have set up a digital video recorder to record broadcasts provided via DVB-C. It is running on a raspberry 3B using TVHeadend and jetty/cling to provide UPnP and other possibilities to access media files. For watching recordings, I wrote an android player app using IJKPlayer, which runs on smartphones, FireTV and AndroidTV.
One hassle when playing media files which are currently beeing recorded is, that IJKPlayer doesn not support timeshifting. Means, when I start playing a currently recording file, I can only watch the length which is known by the player at that moment. Anything which is recorded afterwards can not be played. I need to exit the player activity and start it again. I have resolved that issue by "simulating" a completed recoding using a custom servlet implementation. Since the complete length of the recording is already known, I can use ffmpeg to accomplish this.

Future situation:
I plan to move away from IJKPlayer to ExoPlayer, because it supports hardware playback and is much faster when playing h.264 media. I can of course use the same solution like above, but as far as I have found out yet, ExoPlayer can support media files which are currently being recorded by using the Timeline class. However, I don't seem to find neither a usefull documentation nor any good example. Hence, I would appreciate any help with the timeline object.

Regards
Harry

Answer (score 1):

Looks like my approach won't work. At least, I didn't find a solution. Problem is, that the server returns the stream size as it is during player-start-time. I didn't find a method to update the media duration for "regular" files.

However, I can solve the problem by changing the server side. Instead of accessing a regular file, I convert the file to m3u8 in realtime, using ffmpeg. I then throw the m3u8 URI onto the player and it updates the duration of the stream (while playing) without the need to create any additional code on the client side.